# Marketshare of cross-platform widget libraries?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, widget

For a variety of reasons, we're in the market for a cross-platform widget library.  We're in the somewhat rare situation of not being tied to a particular programming language at this stage, so we get to look at libraries in a language-independent way.

Something we haven't been able to find is any data on market share of various libraries.  Everyone seems to know what the big guns are (Swing, TCL/Tk, Qt, GTK, wxWidgets, etc) but no one seems to have any numbers on use.

Can anyone point me towards some data on marketshare?

Comment: Sidebar: market-share won't be the deciding factor in choosing a toolkit, but it is an interesting metric, and being able to say something like "..and we're using the most widely-used toolkit!" is something the marketing guys like to be able to say.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the TIOBE index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html), one of the Java windowing systems is likely, as far as cross-platform is concerned.  Personally, we're a Qt shop and have had pretty good luck with it, but that's just an anecdote.  You may want to consider not only what the most popular system is but also which system seems to have momentum behind it and is likely to remain popular.